# How to connect to API from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsp page, in which i have two buttons. Start and Stop buttons. When i click on start button calling one jquery, ajax function. But its getting error message.

Please check the code once

```js
//$.support.cors = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;

  url = "http://119.81.26.42/api/order";
  $("#start").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("jghjghjghj");
    var formData = {
      "GUID": "66f1a5ce-3f01-49c3-b825-e0a538ee4fb2",
      "Side": "SELL",
      "Currency": "USD",
      "Metal": "AU",
      "Qty": 0.005,
      "SHA1": "54745c22ac71adbf282a88c698322f26879124d1"
    }
    // var formData = $("#data").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      crossDomain: true,
      beforeSend: function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:", "*"),
          req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"),
          req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-ACCESS_TOKEN, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Authorization, Origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description")

      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(jqxhr, status, errorMsg) {
        alert(status + ": :::::::::===" + errorMsg);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Trade Response</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <button name="button" id="start">Start</button>
    <button name="button" style="margin-left: 294px;" id="stop">Stop</button>
    <input type="text" name="data" value="" id="data" style="display: none;">
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Getting this error:[image]

Comment: Can you edit the code in the question using the "tidy" button?

Answer (score 2):

The headers you are trying to set should come as a part of response and not set in request.

More over there are some specific header that you can't set. for example User-Agent, Content-Type.

Comment: `Content-Type` ***is*** a valid request header (when applicable)